# discord.py get all emojis names and ids from all servers bot is in

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to create a json for my custom emojis. Is there a way to make my bot get all the emojis names and ids from the servers it's in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get them by doing this:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def emojis(self, ctx):
        for emoji in ctx.guild.emojis:
            print(emoji.name, emoji.id)
```